# Match word ignoring same word with extra character in sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

The following [works in Javascript](https://www.regex101.com/r/mW1kJ1/2) as a match:

```
[^\$]fileref.*
```

However, in sed the regex does not match anything. I would like to replace a variable reference in a bash file while ignoring the variable identifier. The premise is that I have a default placeholder file that needs to be updated from a shell script with sed -i. I can't locate a reason as to why sed is having an issue with this expression.

Sed test example:

```
echo -e 'fileref=old\n./executable $fileref' | sed 's/[^\$]fileref.*/fileref=replaced/g'
```

Output from gnu sed (ubuntu or centOS) where no match is found:

```
fileref=old
./executable $fileref
```

Desired output:

```
fileref=replaced
./executable $fileref
```

Comment: sed works line by line, there is no character before "fileref". If you want to match the start of a line use the `^` anchor. As an aside, you don't need to escape the `$` in a character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"No `$` before `fileref`"* can be expressed like this: *"a character that isn't a `$` or no character at all before `fileref`"*

```
echo -e 'fileref=old\n./executable $fileref' | sed 's/\([^$]\|^\)fileref.*/\1fileref=replaced/g'
```

The same with Javascript:

```js
var result = str.replace(/([^$]|^)fileref.*/, '$1fileref=replaced');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo -e 'fileref=old\n./executable $fileref' | sed 's/^fileref.*$/fileref=replaced/g'
```

gives the following

```
fileref=replaced
./executable $fileref
```

by putting in [^\$] you are saying to search for $ at the start of a line